# Fragments and ActionBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have 4 fragments which have different Actionbar (some items) but they have the same dropdown navigation. I've tried to covered some items but the spinner has been moved to the left. I need it on the right.

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHxhO.jpg)
My code in one of the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    menu.findItem(R.id.action_gps).setVisible(false);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter).setVisible(false);
}
```

My menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/m_glass"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_filter"
    android:icon="@drawable/funnel"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_gps"
    android:icon="@drawable/gps"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the issue and the actual requirement

Comment: I've probably missed something, but you complain that your spinner is on the left, yet your spinner has this attribute: android:layout_gravity="left"

Comment: I've tried with the attribute as well. But it didnt help. The spinner is moved because of the hidden items. I dont know how I can keep their space.